# Use Linq To Entities subquery within Select clause to fetch a field value

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-entities

Can I use a Linq To Entities subquery within a (linq to entities) Select clause to fetch a filed value like this:

```
var a = someIQueryable;
var b = IQueryable_2.Select((a,i)=> new Model
{
SomeFiled = someIQueryable.Where(w=>w.AA==a.AA).Select(w=>w.Calls).First()
}).ToList();
```

I am getting "Cannot translate method into store expression".

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Same problem as in your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484675/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-method/5485623#5485623

Comment: This is confusing. You have "a" declared twice - once in 'var a = someIQueryable' and again in the Lambda in the second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is caused by `Select` method (though you could probably provide more details). I'm not sure why you use `Select` overload with index parameter if you do not use it. Use another `Select` overload:

```
var b = IQueryable_2.Select(a => new Model
                     {
                       SomeFiled = someIQueryable.Where(w=>w.AA==a.AA)
                                                 .Select(w=>w.Calls).First()
                     }).ToList();
```