# Can I do a subquery in in SELECT of LINQ to Entities to fill List in model?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to have a subquery in the `.Select` part of a `LINQ to Entities` query in order to fill a `List<string>` inside my view model? I found [Use Linq To Entities subquery within Select clause to fetch a field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485848/use-linq-to-entities-subquery-within-select-clause-to-fetch-a-field-value) but when I try to do that I am getting the error:

> NotImplementedException: Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.ResultOperators.Internal.QueryAnnotationResultOperator

Is this possible to do with Entity Framework 7 and ASP.Net 5 MVC 6?

```
var model = _DbContext.ReleaseVersions
                        .OrderByDescending(rv => rv.DateReleased)
                        .Select(rv => new ReleaseNotesVM()
                        {
                            ID = rv.ID,
                            CurrentVersion = string.Concat(rv.Major, '.', rv.Minor, '.', rv.Patch),
                            ReleaseNotes = _DbContext.ReleaseNotes
                                                    .Where(rn => rn.ReleaseVersionID == rv.ID)
                                                    .Include(rn => rn.ReleaseVersion)
                                                    .Select(rn => rn.Note)
                                                    .ToList()
                        }).FirstOrDefault();
```

ViewModel being filled:

```
public class ReleaseNotesVM
{
    public byte ID { get; set; }
    public string CurrentVersion { get; set; }
    public DateTime CurrentVersionReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> VersionList { get; set; }
    public byte SelectedVersionID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> ReleaseNotes { get; set; }
}
```

DataModel:

```
public class ReleaseVersion
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public byte ID { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateReleased { get; set; }
    public byte Major { get; set; }
    public byte Minor { get; set; }
    public byte Patch { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ReleaseNote> ReleaseNotes { get; set; }
}
public class ReleaseNote
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Note { get; set; }
    public byte ReleaseVersionID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ReleaseVersionID")]
    public ReleaseVersion ReleaseVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `rv.ReleaseNotes` instead of selecting it all over again?

Comment: @GwynBleidd because that is how the linked SO post shows it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I assume correctly, you must have a one-to-many relationship between `ReleaseVersions` and `ReleaseNotes`, which means that there should be a navigation property in the `ReleaseVersion` class referring to the collection of `ReleaseNotes`, enabling you to rewrite your code like this:

```
var model = _DbContext.ReleaseVersions
                    .Include(rv => rv.ReleaseNotes)
                    .OrderByDescending(rv => rv.DateReleased)
                    .Select(rv => new ReleaseNotesVM
                    {
                        ID = rv.ID,
                        CurrentVersion = string.Concat(rv.Major, '.', rv.Minor, '.', rv.Patch),
                        ReleaseNotes = rv.ReleaseNotes.Select(rn => rn.Note).ToList()
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Update**

Use `List<string> ReleaseNotes` instead of `ICollection<string>` in `ReleaseNotesVM`.

Comment: I added `public virtual ICollection<ReleaseNote> ReleaseNotes { get; set; }` to `ReleaseVersion` but now when I do `ReleasEnotes = rv.ReleaseNotes` I get the error `Cannot implicitly convert IColleciton<ReleaseNote> to Icollection<string>`.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete I have updated the answer. Note that I have also updated the select statement itself in order to match your requirements.